# How to send image my friend Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Why i cant send images chat friend? What is the wrong?if i will selected photo my galery just sending text not image. i will send image but showing encoded image text. how to show on imageview.is the problem adapter?I implement picasso and glide but i dont use

Chat  activitiy

```
public class ChatActivity extends BaseActivity {
    private ActivityChatBinding binding;
    private User receiverUser;
    private List<ChatMessage> chatMessages;
    private ChatAdapter chatAdapter;
    private PreferenceManager preferenceManager;
    private FirebaseFirestore database;
    private String conversionId=null;
    private Boolean isReceiverAvailable=false;
    private String encodedImage;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding=ActivityChatBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        setListeners();
        loadReceiverDetails();
        init();
        listenMessages();
    }

   private void setListeners(){
     binding.imageBack.setOnClickListener(v -> onBackPressed());
     binding.layoutSend.setOnClickListener(v -> sendMessage());
     binding.layoutSendPic.setOnClickListener(v -> {
         Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
         intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
         pickImage.launch(intent);
     });
    }

   private void init(){
        preferenceManager=new PreferenceManager(getApplicationContext());
        chatMessages=new ArrayList<>();
        chatAdapter=new ChatAdapter(
                chatMessages,
                getBitmapFromEncodedString(receiverUser.image),
                preferenceManager.getString(Constants.KEY_USER_ID)
        );
        binding.chatRecyclerView.setAdapter(chatAdapter);
        database=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
   }
    private String encodeImage(Bitmap bitmap){
        int previewWidth=150;
        int previewHeight=bitmap.getHeight()*previewWidth/ bitmap.getWidth();
        Bitmap previewBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,previewWidth,previewHeight,false);
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        previewBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,50,byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] bytes=byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        return Base64.encodeToString(bytes,Base64.DEFAULT);
    }
    private final ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> pickImage=registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            result -> {
                if (result.getResultCode()==RESULT_OK){
                    if (result.getData()!=null){
                        Uri imageuri=result.getData().getData();
                        try{
                            InputStream inputStream= getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageuri);
                            Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                            encodedImage=encodeImage(bitmap);
                            sendPic();
                        }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    );

   private void sendPic(){
       HashMap<String,Object>message=new HashMap<>();
       message.put(Constants.KEY_SENDER_ID,preferenceManager.getString(Constants.KEY_USER_ID));
       message.put(Constants.KEY_RECEIVER_ID,receiverUser.id);
       message.put(Constants.KEY_TIMESTAMP,new Date());
       message.put(Constants.KEY_MESSAGE,encodedImage);
       message.put("type","image");
       database.collection(Constants.KEY_COLLECTION_CHAT).add(message);
       if (conversionId!=null){
           updateConversion("photo");
       }else{
           HashMap<String,Object>conversion =new HashMap<>();
           conversion.put(Constants.KEY_SENDER_ID,preferenceManager.getString(Constants.KEY_USER_ID));
           conversion.put(Constants.KEY_SENDER_NAME,preferenceManager.getString(Constants.KEY_NAME));
           conversion.put(Constants.KEY_SENDER_IMAGE,preferenceManager.getString(Constants.KEY_IMAGE));
           conversion.put(Constants.KEY_RECEIVER_ID,receiverUser.id);
           conversion.put(Constants.KEY_RECEIVER_NAME,receiverUser.name);
           conversion.put(Constants.KEY_RECEIVER_IMAGE,receiverUser.image);
           conversion.put(Constants.KEY_LAST_MESSAGE,encodedImage);
           conversion.put(Constants.KEY_TIMESTAMP,new Date());
           addConversion(conversion);
       }
   }
   private void sendMessage(){
        HashMap<String, Object> message=new HashMap<>();
        message.put(Constants.KEY_SENDER_ID,preferenceManager.getString(Constants.KEY_USER_ID));
        message.put(Constants.KEY_RECEIVER_ID,receiverUser.id);
        message.put(Constants.KEY_MESSAGE,binding.inputMessage.getText().toString());
        message.put(Constants.KEY_TIMESTAMP,new Date());

        database.collection(Constants.KEY_COLLECTION_CHAT).add(message);
        if (conversionId!=null){
            updateConversion(binding.inputMessage.getText().toString());
        }else {
            HashMap<String,Object>conversion =new HashMap<>();
            conversion.put(Constants.KEY_SENDER_ID,preferenceManager.getString(Constants.KEY_USER_ID));
            conversion.put(Constants.KEY_SENDER_NAME,preferenceManager.getString(Constants.KEY_NAME));
            conversion.put(Constants.KEY_SENDER_IMAGE,preferenceManager.getString(Constants.KEY_IMAGE));
            conversion.put(Constants.KEY_RECEIVER_ID,receiverUser.id);
            conversion.put(Constants.KEY_RECEIVER_NAME,receiverUser.name);
            conversion.put(Constants.KEY_RECEIVER_IMAGE,receiverUser.image);
            conversion.put(Constants.KEY_LAST_MESSAGE,binding.inputMessage.getText().toString());
            conversion.put(Constants.KEY_TIMESTAMP,new Date());
            addConversion(conversion);
        }
        binding.inputMessage.setText(null);
    }

   private void listenAvailabilityReceiver(){
        database.collection(Constants.KEY_COLLECTION_USERS).document(
                receiverUser.id
        ).addSnapshotListener(ChatActivity.this,(value, error) -> {
            if (error!=null){
                return;
            }
            if (value!=null){
                if (value.getLong(Constants.KEY_AVAILABILITY)!=null){
                    int availability= Objects.requireNonNull(
                            value.getLong(Constants.KEY_AVAILABILITY)
                    ).intValue();
                    isReceiverAvailable=availability==1;
                }
            }
            if (isReceiverAvailable){
                binding.textAvailability.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else{
                binding.textAvailability.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }

   private void listenMessages(){
        database.collection(Constants.KEY_COLLECTION_CHAT)
                .whereEqualTo(Constants.KEY_SENDER_ID,preferenceManager.getString(Constants.KEY_USER_ID))
                .whereEqualTo(Constants.KEY_RECEIVER_ID,receiverUser.id)
                .addSnapshotListener(eventListener);
        database.collection(Constants.KEY_COLLECTION_CHAT)
                .whereEqualTo(Constants.KEY_SENDER_ID,receiverUser.id)
                .whereEqualTo(Constants.KEY_RECEIVER_ID,preferenceManager.getString(Constants.KEY_USER_ID))
                .addSnapshotListener(eventListener);
    }

   @SuppressLint({"NotifyDataSetChanged", "NewApi"})
   private final EventListener<QuerySnapshot> eventListener=(value, error)->{
        if (error!=null){
            return;
        }
        if (value!=null) {
            int count = chatMessages.size();
            for (DocumentChange documentChange : value.getDocumentChanges()) {
                if (documentChange.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                    ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage();
                    chatMessage.senderId = documentChange.getDocument().getString(Constants.KEY_SENDER_ID);
                    chatMessage.receiverId = documentChange.getDocument().getString(Constants.KEY_RECEIVER_ID);
                    chatMessage.message = documentChange.getDocument().getString(Constants.KEY_MESSAGE);
                    chatMessage.dateTime = getReadableDateTime(documentChange.getDocument().getDate(Constants.KEY_TIMESTAMP));
                    chatMessage.dateObject =documentChange.getDocument().getDate(Constants.KEY_TIMESTAMP);
                    chatMessages.add(chatMessage);
                }
            }
            Collections.sort(chatMessages, Comparator.comparing(o -> o.dateObject));

            if (count==0){
                chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }else{
                chatAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(chatMessages.size(),chatMessages.size());
                binding.chatRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(chatMessages.size()-1);
            }
            binding.chatRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        binding.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (conversionId==null){
            checkForConversion();
        }
    };

   private Bitmap getBitmapFromEncodedString(String encodedImage){
        byte[] bytes= Base64.decode(encodedImage,Base64.DEFAULT);
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes,0,bytes.length);
    }
   private void loadReceiverDetails(){
        receiverUser=(User) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(Constants.KEY_USER);
        binding.textName.setText(receiverUser.name);
    }


    private String getReadableDateTime(Date date){
        return new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd,yyyy- hh:mm a", Locale.getDefault()).format(date);
    }

    private void addConversion(HashMap<String,Object>conversion){
       database.collection(Constants.KEY_COLLECTION_CONVERSATIONS)
               .add(conversion)
               .addOnSuccessListener(documentReference -> conversionId=documentReference.getId());
    }

   private void updateConversion(String message){
        DocumentReference   documentReference=
                database.collection(Constants.KEY_COLLECTION_CONVERSATIONS).document(conversionId);
        documentReference.update(
                Constants.KEY_LAST_MESSAGE,message,
                Constants.KEY_TIMESTAMP,new Date()
        );
    }

   private void checkForConversion(){
       if (chatMessages.size()!=0){
           checkForConversionRemotely(
                   preferenceManager.getString(Constants.KEY_USER_ID),
                   receiverUser.id
           );
           checkForConversionRemotely(
                   receiverUser.id,
                   preferenceManager.getString(Constants.KEY_USER_ID)
           );
       }
    }

   private void checkForConversionRemotely(String senderId,String receiverId){
       database.collection(Constants.KEY_COLLECTION_CONVERSATIONS)
               .whereEqualTo(Constants.KEY_SENDER_ID,senderId)
               .whereEqualTo(Constants.KEY_RECEIVER_ID,receiverId)
               .get()
               .addOnCompleteListener(conversionOnCompleteListener);
    }


   private final OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot> conversionOnCompleteListener=task ->{
       if (task.isSuccessful()&&task.getResult()!=null&&task.getResult().getDocuments().size()>0){
           DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot=task.getResult().getDocuments().get(0);
           conversionId=documentSnapshot.getId();
       }
    };

    @Override
   protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        listenAvailabilityReceiver();
    }
}
```

Chat Adapter

```
    package com.example.chat.adapters;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import com.example.chat.databinding.ItemContainerReceivedMessageBinding;
import com.example.chat.databinding.ItemContainerSentMessageBinding;
import com.example.chat.models.ChatMessage;

import java.util.List;

public class ChatAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private final List<ChatMessage> chatMessages;
    private final Bitmap receiverProfileImage;
    private final String senderId;

    public static final int VIEW_TYPE_SENT=1;
    public static final int VIEW_TYPE_RECEIVED=2;

    public ChatAdapter(List<ChatMessage> chatMessages, Bitmap receiverProfileImage, String senderId) {
        this.chatMessages = chatMessages;
        this.receiverProfileImage = receiverProfileImage;
        this.senderId = senderId;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType==VIEW_TYPE_SENT){
            return new SentMessageViewHolder(
                    ItemContainerSentMessageBinding.inflate(
                            LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()),
                            parent,
                            false
                    )
            );
        }else{
            return new ReceivedMessageViewHolder(
                    ItemContainerReceivedMessageBinding.inflate(
                            LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()),
                            parent,
                            false
                    )
            );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (getItemViewType(position)==VIEW_TYPE_SENT){
        ((SentMessageViewHolder)holder).setData(chatMessages.get(position));
    }else{
        ((ReceivedMessageViewHolder)holder).setData(chatMessages.get(position),receiverProfileImage);
    }
}
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return chatMessages.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(chatMessages .get(position).senderId.equals(senderId)){
            return VIEW_TYPE_SENT;
        }else {
            return VIEW_TYPE_RECEIVED;
        }
    }

    static class SentMessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private final ItemContainerSentMessageBinding binding;

        SentMessageViewHolder(ItemContainerSentMessageBinding itemContainerSentMessageBinding){
            super(itemContainerSentMessageBinding.getRoot());
            binding=itemContainerSentMessageBinding;
        }
        void setData(ChatMessage chatMessage){
           
            binding.textSentMessage.setText(chatMessage.message);
          
            binding.textDatetime.setText(chatMessage.dateTime);

        }
    }
    static class ReceivedMessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private final ItemContainerReceivedMessageBinding binding;

        ReceivedMessageViewHolder(ItemContainerReceivedMessageBinding itemContainerReceivedMessageBinding){
            super(itemContainerReceivedMessageBinding.getRoot());
            binding=itemContainerReceivedMessageBinding;
        }
        void setData(ChatMessage chatMessage,Bitmap receiverProfileImage){
        
            binding.textDatetime.setText(chatMessage.dateTime);
            binding.imageProfile.setImageBitmap(receiverProfileImage);
        }
    }
}
```

item_container_sent_messages.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:padding="4dp">

    <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
        android:id="@+id/friendsImage"
        app:riv_oval="true"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/textSentMessage"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textSentMessage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_sent_message"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:paddingStart="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="12dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_max="wrap"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/friendsImage"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.75"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sendPicture"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:paddingStart="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="12dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_max="wrap"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/friendsImage"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.75"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textDatetime"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:textColor="@color/gray"
        android:textSize="8sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/textSentMessage"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textSentMessage"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use any third-party website(base64 to jpg) to confirm if the `receiverUser.image` is resulting in the correct image or not. As for me, everything looks good in your code except this line.

Comment: i think problem to adapter bec i dont see image on the chat 'receiverUser.image' do not anything. but i cant solve the problem. ty for answer